# I Am Having Trouble Executing a list as a string for an automated function

Tags: python, string, arraylist, instagram

I have a school project where my program must execute this code to follow two users:

```
def followWithUsername(self):
    usernames = ['therock', 'justinbieber']
    self.driver.get('https://instagram.com/' + str(usernames) + '/')
    time.sleep(3)
    followButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
    if (followButton.text != 'Following'):
        followButton.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("You are already following this user.")
```

I've tried various methods but this will not separate the usernames from eachother and execute it one by one

Comment: You're accessing the list. Perhaps what you were trying to do was access it's elements? As in: usernames[0], for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
def followWithUsername(self):
    usernames = ['therock', 'justinbieber']
    for name in usernames:
        self.driver.get('https://instagram.com/' + name + '/')
        time.sleep(3)
        followButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
        if (followButton.text != 'Following'):
            followButton.click()
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            print("You are already following this user.")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will do more studying on for loops and rewrite so that I can comprehend what is being done here.

Comment: @BotBot Your welcome :-), keep up the good work learning python :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the list to be able to execute this over multiple values. Given this is a school project, I'm hesitant to provide you a complete answer.

This is best achieved via using `for loops`, you can read more about these here: [Python FOR Loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

You will encounter and use `for` loops quite a lot and they can be extremely useful here is an example:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# This translates to "For each item stored in the list 'values' perform the following code"

for item in values: 
    print(item)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me in the right direction, I will study the for loops so I can actually comprehend what is going on in my code. I plan to rewrite for memory